# Calculating it wrong in a C++ coin change algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm

So, I am trying to build this program, where I am suppose to take an input from a user which is a total amount and an amount which is the paid amount. Now, the balance should be broken down into $10, $5, $1, quarters, dimes and nickles. But the below program/code, tells me the total number of quarters, dimes, and nickles in the balance and not the remaining. For example . If the total amount is 5.76 and paid amount is $15 then it should show, zero $10, one $5, 4 $1, zero $.25, 2 $.10 , zero $.05 and four $.01 .

Please tell me whats wrong in the code here?

Comment: Have you tried running it in a debugger?

Comment: Where are you calculating the number of $10, $5 and $1 bills?

Comment: Why would you expect `.01` to be displayed when all of your data is represented by integers?

Comment: You tell us what's wrong. You say that it's supposed to ask for a total amount and a paid amount. What does it do instead?

Comment: Hello, say the change is 10 then it tells me that there are 1 $10 and 2 $5. Instead it should show 1 $10 and zero $5.

Comment: Your code as shown doesn't say anything about $10 or $5.  It starts at quarters and goes down.

Comment: Your question sounds like "Do my homework plz". Try to put more research effort in it.

Comment: Besides not handling bills, the code is correct (assuming the proper input). What were you expecting? How does the behavior of your program differ from the expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest fix is to get the number as a float then multiplying it by 100 then saving it as int.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ( )
{
    float userNUmber;
    int change, quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies; // declare variables
    cout <<"Enter the amount of money: ";
    cin >> userNUmber; // input the amount of change
    change = userNUmber * 100;
    quarters = change / 25; // calculate the number of quarters
    change = change % 25; // calculate remaining change needed
    dimes = change / 10; // calculate the number of dimes
    change = change % 10; // calculate remaining change needed
    nickels = change / 5; // calculate the number of nickels
    pennies = change % 5; // calculate pennies

    cout << "\nQuarters: " << quarters << endl; // display # of quarters
    cout << " Dimes: " << dimes << endl; // display # of dimes
    cout << " Nickels: " << nickels << endl; // display # of nickels
    cout <<" Pennies: " << pennies << endl; // display # of pennies
    system("Pause");
    return (0);
}
```

Also to do it in a loop is something like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main ( )
{
    float userNUmber;
    int change, quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies; // declare variables

    cout <<"Enter the amount of money: ";
    cin >> userNUmber; // input the amount of change
    change = userNUmber * 100;

    vector<int> coins(4, 0);
    coins[0] = 25; coins[1] = 10; coins[2] = 5; coins[3] = 1;
    vector<string> coinsName(4, "");
    coinsName[0] = "Quaters"; coinsName[1] = "Dimes"; coinsName[2] = "Nickels"; coinsName[3] = "Pennies";

    for(size_t i = 0; i < coins.size(); ++i)
    {
        int numberOfCoins = change / coins[i]; // calculate the number of quarters
        change = change % coins[i]; // calculate remaining change needed
        cout << coinsName[i] << ": " << numberOfCoins << endl; // display # of quarters
    }
    system("Pause");
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: @caeasar.. can this also be done in a for loop?

Comment: Because it's totally wrong: "Enter the amount ... in cents". So if I enter 83 (as in 83 cents). The result should be 3 quarters, 1 nickle and 3 pennies. What you'll get from your code is: 332 quarters.

Comment: It's asking for input in _cents_. At the very least change the instructions.

Comment: The comment is wrong, but the code works fine and just the way i wanted. Caesar understood that. The comment wrong was my fault..

Comment: @user15169 Yeah, I just updated the answer so that it  shows.

Comment: @SaniHuttunen Didn't write the code. I just fixed it like he said.

Comment: There is nothing in the question that can make you come to the conclusion to multiply with 100 and get the correct result. This question and answer is fake.

Comment: I'd really be happy to get 30 quarters for my 75 cents...

Comment: @netcoder: Actually 300 quarters for 75 cents... :)

Comment: @SaniHuttunen I don't know if you noticed, but not a lot of things are straight forward in OP posts. Like he talks about 5 and 10 bills he doesn't have it in his code.

Comment: @Caesar: Nothing is straight forward... everything is backwards... :)
Nothing in the OP makes sense. But if the OP doesn't make sense then your answer cannot either.

Comment: @SaniHuttunen You caught me. I have been planning this for years. First start an account than gain some reputation and medals. Than to spin it all off wait a few months than build an extra account and ask a question that only I can answer. *Rolls eyes*

Comment: @Caesar: :) (15 or more)

Comment: @SaniHuttunen: I'd content myself with 30 ;-)