# using c mod operator to work out coin denominations

Tags: c, operator-keyword, modulus

I've been taught how to use the mod operator in c to work out change for a denomination of coins for example: if given $22, and need to work out how many $10, $5, $2 and $1 make up that 22 then:

```
22/10 = 2 of $10
22%10 = 2
Therefore since only $2 left:
2/5 = 0
2%5 = 2
2/2 = 1 of $2
2%2 = 0 
So 2 $10 and 1 $2.
```

My question is though how exactly can I write this as code so that it will work for any given amount of change?I'm still a beginner so I'm having a bit of difficulty. I appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: have you tried anything? if you post your code, we will help you with it

Comment: Useful answer on SO: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/12433941/952747](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12433941/952747)

Comment: Ok I'll have an attempt and also I looked at that link it's written in c++ I can't understand that but thanks anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if the maximum value of a note/coin is $10 (sorry if this sounds trivial, but I'm not a U. S. citizen):

```
int vals[] = { 10, 5, 2, 1 };
int amount = 22;

for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(vals) / sizeof(vals[0]); i++) {
    printf("%d piece of $%d\n", amount / vals[i], vals[i]);
    amount %= vals[i];
}
```